# Make registration form work when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, registration, noscript

I'm trying to make this registration form work even if javascript is disabled, I don't know where to begin. Would really appreciate some help!

HTML:

```
<form name="news" onsubmit="validateForm()" action="thanks.html">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Namn" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-postadress" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send" id="send">

</form>
```

Js file:

```
function validateForm()
{
if( document.getElementById('name').value === '' ){
  alert("Please enter your name!");
  return false;
}

var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;

if(document.news.email.value.match(emailExp))
{
    return true;
}

else
{
    alert("Please enter your e-mail!");
    document.news.email.focus(); 
    return false;
}
}

function init()
{
var validate = document.getElementById("send");
validate.onclick = validateForm;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen at thanks.html? You know that won't process the $_GET request by default, right? Point being, if JS is disabled, it is up to the server side script to run validation. Your action attribute should target the file for validation, or at least target a file that will process the request and include the validation script

Comment: It's not recommended to use client side validation anyway - only for small/simple things like checking if the user forgot to enter something for userfriendliness. If this is the case, you can use HTML5 now or in your way. But overall, it is best to do the real checks on the server-side (they can't manipulate that if programmed well).

Answer (score 0):

What server-side technology are you using?
There really aren't ways to validate on client side without JavaScript. 
Use the built-in server-side validation controls in ASP.NET or MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Put your form validation on the server, but it appears your action is thanks.html which in most cases doesn't have any server side logic.  Actually, I'm not sure how the form works with javascript other than to give the impression you took down their information.